# How to save semaphore in Aerospike?

Tags: redis, aerospike

We have been using Aeropsike exentsively as key-value store only. However now I couldn't find a way to actually save a lock in Aeropspike like the way we do in [Redis](https://redis.io/topics/distlock).

I guess, I can always save native application lock as blobs, but that means I will be limited to a particular implementation in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't believe you can "save" locks in Aerospike.  Any form of locking has to be implemented at the Application level and then you have to deal with the locking client abandoning the lock.

Comment: Thanks, I was waiting from someone from Aerospike community to confirm. In that case I will evaluate Redis and Hazelcast, as I would like to avoid implementing at application.

Comment: Why do you need locks? Are you trying to do multi-record transactions?

Comment: BTW, if you just want to do a read modify write on the same record- Aerospike does provide a way to do an equivalent optimistic locking implementation using the generation counter - CAS - check and set or compare and set - using the EXPECT_GENEQUAL policy.

Comment: Yup, I know about it. I could use it to maintain application lock object(say java's ReenterantLock), but I think a native lock is a good utility to have, something like Hazelcast's ILock

Comment: Let’s be clear, Redlock for Redis is a badly implemented DLM, and the distributed computing community tore it a new one in reviews. Hazelcast failed Jepsen spectacularly, so you cannot build a DLM over it.Google is your friend for that research.  Aerospike EE with linearizable strong consistency _can_ be used to create such a service.

Comment: I have read the jepsen tests for all three, I know that aerospike shines there. But I was hoping to not create such service myself, but use a native one. Redisson provides locking over redis, and since I now am planning to use single instance and I require mostly locking not linearizable, I think I am okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read Martin Kleppmann's [Redlock Discussion](https://storify.com/martinkl/redlock-discussion). It covers the [responses](https://twitter.com/kellabyte/status/697095228696584193) people in the distributed systems community had to Antirez's debating the topic, following Kleppmann's earlier article [How to do distributed locking](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html).

Building a [DLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager) is not a trivial problem at all, and Redlock fails as one. If you are up for it, you can consider writing such a thing over the [linearizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) [strong consistency mode](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/consistency.html#strong-consistency-mode) of Aerospike Enterprise Edition 4.0.

As opposed to Redis and its variants, [Aerospike EE 4.0 passes Jepsen](https://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-4-strong-consistency-and-jepsen/).

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer, but bad mouthing Antirez wasn't nice! I know he can get quite passionate in the discussion, but he still has my respect. Redis is open source and its not his job to always come up with best working stuff.

Comment: btw, I had already read all the discussion on Redlock, I am not using that for sure.

Comment: You can contribute to open source and still be a huge crank, for example Linus. You can also be a mansplainer - someone with limited knowledge who will still passionately 'explain' to an academic all about a field they do research in, which is why I put in Kellabyte's tweet in there.  I think 'mansplainer' in this context is (a) factual and (b) hardly bad mouthing.